# Math Formula in C for RuneScape experience

Tags: c, math, formula

I'm trying to implement a mathematical formula in C that calculates the XP needed for a certain Runescape level and I am not getting the correct output. Level 1 gives "75" XP and Level 99 gives "11059837". What is wrong with my implementation? I cant figure it out. Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    /* Determines the XP needed for a Runescape Lv */
    int lv;
    printf("Enter a Lv(1-99): ");
    scanf("%d", &lv);

    if(lv > 99 || lv < 1) {
        printf("Invalid Lv");
    } else {
        int xp = 0;
        int output = 0;

        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= lv; i++) {
            xp += floor((i + (300 * (pow(2, (i/7))))));
        }
        output = floor((xp/4));
        printf("The amount of XP needed for Lv%d is %d\n", lv, output);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The math formula is:  [image: formula]

Comment: My guess would be the integer division in `pow(2, (i/7))`.

Comment: Are you confident that that formula is Integer math? There is no meaning to floor unless they are using floating point... (such as in the `i/7`).

Comment: You are calling floor but doing all of your math with ints.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but since the summation in the equation you linked to has an upper bound of "level - 1", you should have a `for loop` like this instead of what you have: `for(i = 1; i < lv; i++){`

Comment: You should cast the variable `i` as a `float`, as in `pow(2, ((float)i/7))`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a simple test with level 1.

```
1/7 is 0.14... 
2 to the power of (1/7) is 1.104...
times 300, we obtain 331.2...
add 1 and take the integer part, you'll obtain 332 which divided by 4 taking the integer part is 83
```

The output according to this formula shall be 83.

The problem is that `i` is defined as `int`, and 7 is an `int` constant.  The conversion rules of C, make the compiler understands this as an integer division, with an integer result:

```
integer division of 1 by 7 is 0 (remains 1)
2 to the power of 0 is always 1.  
times 300 is 300
add 1 and take the floor you obtain 301, which divided by 4 taking the integer part is 75, the value that you've found.
```

How to solve the problem ?  Change your expression slightly:

```
        xp += floor((i + (300 * (pow(2, (i / 7.0))))));
```

Writing `7.0` makes the constant a double.  Dividing an integer `i` by a double is according to the implicit conversion rules understood as a floating point operation with a double result.  `pow()` is itself a double function, so that the rest of the expression works as designed.

With this change the level 99 gives 14 391 160.

According to [this table](http://www.tip.it/runescape/pages/view/xp_table.htm), the result is correct (if you understadn your output as the experience points needed to get to the next level).

***Trick to know:***  In case of doubt, in a mathematical formula, when mixing `int` and `float` or `double`, you can also cast explicitely to the right type, for example `(double)i / 7`.